# converting windows form from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I have seen a number of issues on this subject, but none of them with the results that I am getting.  I had a windows form app that worked perfectly with VS2008.  We recently switched over to VS2010.  I converted successfully.  However, when I go to run it, it does nothing.

I receieved this ouput:

> 'DataVariablesManagerForm.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'DataVariablesManagerForm.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'DataVariablesManagerForm.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>
> etc.

Any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help at all?

> "After hours of effort to get it right, I figured out that if I change
>   the TARGET FRAMEWORK from 3.5 to 4 it works. When I change the TARGET
>   FRAMEWORK back to 3.5 again, it stops working."
>
> As my understanding, The Visual Studio 2010 includes only the .NET
>   Framework 4. To target earlier versions of the .NET Framework, we need
>   to have the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed. To download and install
>   the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, see Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service
>   Pack 1 on the Microsoft Download Center website. Hope it could help.

(Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/0f9f399f-4467-413f-b74e-f0d5e55f4849)